# Registro en android Studio

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy creando una app en android y en el momento pues realmente mis conociminetos son algo basicos, ya he creado varias cosas, pero tengo un incoveniente, resulta que estoy haciendo el registro de usuarios y lo que pasa es que queria validar si un correo ya estaba registrado y ya lo logre solo que ahora cuando registra un usuario nuevo sale error en la app y apesar de todo si hace el registro

anexo mi codigo

```
    final String password = mcontraseña.getText().toString().trim();
    final String confirm = mconfirma.getText().toString().trim();
        final String name = mNombre.getText().toString().trim();
        final String ciudad = mciudad.getText().toString().trim();
        final String direccion = mdireccion.getText().toString().trim();
        final String documento = mdocumento.getText().toString().trim();
        final String numero = mnumero.getText().toString().trim();
        final String departamento = mdepartamento.getText().toString().trim();

        final String email = mEmailFiedl.getText().toString().trim();


        mAuth2.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                final boolean[] flag = {false};
                for (DataSnapshot IDGenerado : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String usernameTaken = IDGenerado.child("correo").getValue(String.class);
                    if (email.equals(usernameTaken.toLowerCase())) {
                        flag[0] = true; // Indica que ya fue tomado el username
                    }
                }
                // si el flag nunca se marco como verdadero, entonces no se ha tomado el username
                if (flag[0] != false) {

                    mEmailFiedl.setError("Este correo ya se encuentra Registrado");

                } else {
                    if (Objects.equals(password, confirm)) {
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ingresa Tu correo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }

                        if (!validarEmail(email)) {
                            mEmailFiedl.setError("Email no válido");
                            return;
                        }

                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Has Ingresado una contraseña!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }

                        if (password.length() < 6) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La Contraseña Debe ser mayor De 6 caracteres!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }


                        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(registro.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                        Toast.makeText(registro.this, "Tu Usuario Ha sido creado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
                                        DatabaseReference currentUserDB = mDatabase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                                        currentUserDB.child("Nombre").setValue(name);
                                        currentUserDB.child("ciudad").setValue(ciudad);
                                        currentUserDB.child("correo").setValue(email);
                                        currentUserDB.child("documento").setValue(documento);
                                        currentUserDB.child("numero").setValue(numero);
                                        currentUserDB.child("direccion").setValue(direccion);
                                        currentUserDB.child("departamento").setValue(departamento);
                                        currentUserDB.child("image").setValue("default");

                                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Toast.makeText(registro.this, "Error no hemos podido registrarte" + task.getException(),
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {
                                            startActivity(new Intent(registro.this, principal.class));
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    }


                                });


                    } else {
                        mconfirma.setError("Las Contraseñas no son iguales");
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

y otra pequeña parte del codigo `

```
mAuth2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();`
```

agradezco su ayuda y colaboracion

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido al sitio!,  " sale error en la app"???,  es conveniente agregar que tipo de error obtienes para que los desarrolladores tengan más información para ayudar a solucionar tu problema. Te invito a realizar el [tour] para 

conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 

[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! para que 

obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Comment: Hola David, suena a que estas implementando mucha lógica que ya viene por defecto implementada en la autenticación de Firebase. podrias detallar mejor cual es el objetivo?

Comment: david firebase te permite saber si un correo ya fue usado por otro o no cuando haces el signUp. Para validar si esta o no chequeado el email existe una funcion para eso .isEmailVerified

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto te puede ayudar mucho a mejorar tu codigo

**Esto seria a la hora de crear un usario nuevo:**

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");

                                final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getUser();
                                textViewStatus.setText(R.string.profile_created);

                                //Mandamos un correo de verificacion al correo dado como entrada
                                if (firebaseUser != null) {
                                    textViewStatus.setText(R.string.sending_verification_email);
                                    firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification()
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
                                                if (task1.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
                                                    textViewStatus.setText(R.string.verification_email);

                                                    MDToast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.verification_email), MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_SUCCESS).show();
                                                }
                                            });

                                    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                            .setDisplayName(companyName)
                                            .build();

                                    firebaseUser.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(task12 -> {
                                                if (task12.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
                                                    textViewStatus.setText(R.string.profile_updated);

                                                    writeInRealTimeDatabase(firebaseUser, ...your_data);
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            } else {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                animationView.cancelAnimation();
                                Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                try {
                                    throw Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException());
                                } catch (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "signUpFragment" + e.getMessage());
                                    textInputLayoutPasswordSignUp.setError("Contraseña débil. Por favor intente otra.");
                                    textInputLayoutPasswordSignUp.requestFocus();
                                } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "signUpFragment" + e.getMessage());
                                    txtInputEmailSignUp.setError("Correo inválido.");
                                    txtInputEmailSignUp.requestFocus();


                                } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
                                    switch (e.getErrorCode()) {
                                        case "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE":
                                            Log.e(TAG, "signUpFragment" + e.getMessage());
                                            MDToast.makeText(context, "El correo está actualmente en uso por otro usuario", MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
                                            txtInputEmailSignUp.setError("Email no válido");
                                            txtInputEmailSignUp.requestFocus();
                                            break;
                                        case "ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL":
                                            Log.e(TAG, "signUpFragment" + e.getMessage());
                                            MDToast.makeText(context, "Esta cuenta existe. Solo se permite una cuenta por correo.", MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
                                            txtInputEmailSignUp.setError("Email no válido");
                                            txtInputEmailSignUp.requestFocus();
                                            break;

                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "signUpFragment" + e.getMessage());
                                    MDToast.makeText(context, "Error de red. Red desconectada o no existe conexión a internet", MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e));
```

**Ahora cuando quieres autenticar a un usuario ya registrado y su email verificado lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:**

```
private void signInWithEmailAndPassw(String email, String password) {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    animationView.pauseAnimation();
                    if (user != null && user.isEmailVerified()) {
                        //loadToast.success();

                        startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
                        getActivity().finish();

                    } else if (user != null && !user.isEmailVerified()) {
                        //MDToast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.check_email), MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
                        //loadToast.error();
                        Snackbar.make(snackView, R.string.resend_verification_email, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Enviar", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
                                        MDToast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.verification_email), MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_SUCCESS).show();
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Email not sent.");
                                    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                                    MDToast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.error_mail), MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
                                });
                            }
                        }).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                    loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    animationView.cancelAnimation();

                    //loadToast.error();
                    try {
                        throw Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException());
                    } catch (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
                        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                        textInputEditTextPassword.setError("Contraseña débil. Por favor intente otra.");
                        textInputEditTextPassword.requestFocus();
                    } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                        String wrongPassword = getString(R.string.fui_error_invalid_password);
                        String wrongEmail = getString(R.string.fui_invalid_email_address);
                        if (e.getErrorCode().equals(wrongPassword)) {
                            textInputEditTextPassword.setError("Contraseña incorrecta.");
                            textInputEditTextPassword.requestFocus();
                        } else if (e.getErrorCode().equals(wrongEmail)) {
                            textInputEditTextUser.setError("Correo inválido.");
                            textInputEditTextUser.requestFocus();
                        }

                    } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
                        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                        Log.e(TAG, "LoginFragment: " + e.getMessage());
                        switch (e.getErrorCode()) {
                            case "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE":
                                MDToast.makeText(context, "El correo está actualmente en uso por otro usuario", MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
                                textInputEditTextUser.setError("Email no válido");
                                textInputEditTextUser.requestFocus();
                                break;
                            case "ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL":
                                MDToast.makeText(context, "Esta cuenta existe. Solo se permite una cuenta por correo.", MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
                                textInputEditTextUser.setError("Email no válido");
                                textInputEditTextUser.requestFocus();
                                break;

                        }
                    } catch (FirebaseNetworkException e) {
                        MDToast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.bad_connection),
                                MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure " + e.getMessage(), e);
                        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        MDToast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(),
                                MDToast.LENGTH_LONG, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR).show();
                        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Aqui le damos la opcion de que pueda reenviar su correo en caso de que no le haya llegado o ya haya caducado.

Espero que te ayude un saludo.